# Pandas shift entire column up conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
     year  dayofyear            x      
360  2014        361  109357.2798  
361  2014        362  106484.6514   
362  2014        363  112627.1748   
363  2014        364   99750.2315   
364  2014        365   56330.7660  
365  2014        366          NaN  
366  2015          1   60859.1082   
367  2015          2   99507.1793    
368  2015          3   92279.8554  
369  2015          4  106590.6594
```

I would like to shift all values in column 'x' below the NaN up one position. Values in 'year' and 'dayofyear' should remain the same.

Thus the desired output would look as follows:

```
     year  dayofyear            x      
360  2014        361  109357.2798  
361  2014        362  106484.6514   
362  2014        363  112627.1748   
363  2014        364   99750.2315   
364  2014        365   56330.7660  
365  2014        366   60859.1082  
366  2015          1   99507.1793   
367  2015          2   92279.8554     
368  2015          3  106590.6594  
369  2015          4   NaN
```

I have played around with pd.shift(-1), but this shifts the entire column. I only need the values below the NaN shifted back by 1, does anyone has a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [401]: s = df['x'].isnull()

In [403]: df.loc[s[s].index[0]:, 'x'] = df['x'].shift(-1)

In [404]: df
Out[404]:
     year  dayofyear            x
360  2014        361  109357.2798
361  2014        362  106484.6514
362  2014        363  112627.1748
363  2014        364   99750.2315
364  2014        365   56330.7660
365  2014        366   60859.1082
366  2015          1   99507.1793
367  2015          2   92279.8554
368  2015          3  106590.6594
369  2015          4          NaN
```

---

Details

```
In [405]: s
Out[405]:
360    False
361    False
362    False
363    False
364    False
365     True
366    False
367    False
368    False
369    False
Name: x, dtype: bool

In [406]: s[s].index
Out[406]: Int64Index([365], dtype='int64')

In [407]: s[s].index[0]
Out[407]: 365
```